# White margins ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

Using **jupyter notebook** (doesn't happen in RStudio), when plotting a graph with ggplot and reducing the ratio of the plot:

```
ggplot(data)+
     theme(aspect.ratio=.5)
```

or

```
ggplot(data)+
     coord_fixed(ratio = 0.20)
```

white margins appear in the top and bottom side of the graph:

See attached an example of the complete code:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4))
ggplot(data)+
     geom_point(aes(x,y))+
     coord_fixed(ratio = 0.20)
```

**Jupyter Notebook output picture:**

[image]

**Diagram:**

[image]

how can I solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If you'd like better/any responses, please provide a bit of sample data to make it easy for folks to help you. You can run the code following code to do so. data <- dput(mydataframe)'

Comment: Does this solution help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473128/r-changing-ggplot-plot-size-in-jupyter