# Resize R plot in juputer notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, image-resizing, geom-bar

I cannot somehow figure out how to resize the R graph, I am getting in my JupyterNotebook. No matter what I put in width or hight in `options`, it still remains this same.

The value of `jobmemberid` is a numeric data that I had to turn into a character. I feel like the bars are also of a different size, so it would be great to know if I can keep them constant.

[image]

Any hints how to go about it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473128/r-changing-ggplot-plot-size-in-jupyter

Comment: Already checked it out and it's not resolving my problem. I tried to use ```print(pl, vp=grid::viewport(width=unit(10, 'inch'), height=unit(8, 'inch')))``` and without success